# Disable iOS11 Update Password ActionSheet

Tags: ios, ios11, autofill

Is there a way to disable the iOS11's "Update Password" ActionSheet (Part of iOS11's password autofill feature https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/) which is presented after the user logs in and I navigate to a new ViewController. Because sometimes it's presented even though the login operation was not successful.

I want to indicate to the OS that the login was not successful and therefore the password existing in the Keychain should not be replaced with the new one.

Answer (score 0):

You can set nil to your text field, such that the AutoFill UI will not update password because there is no appropriate account to update.

With a little delay, you set the original text back to the text field.